# Use CSS to add space and a drop-cap after an image

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I think there's a way to do this with the :after pseudo-element, but I can't quite figure it out.

This is for a CMS and I don't have the ability to edit what's in between the `div class=entry-text` tags.

I have a `div` into which a `<p>` is inserted, sometimes with an `<a><img /></a>` before the text, but sometimes just the text.

I want that text to be spaced below the image if it exists, and I want a drop-cap on that text.

```
<div class="entry-text">
  <p>This is some text</p>
</div>

<div class="entry-text">
  <p><a href="#"><img src="myimage.jpg" class="entry-image" /></a>
  This is some text</p>
</div>

<style>
 div.entry-text > p::first-letter, div.entry-text > p > a::after::first-letter { 
     float: left;
     color: red;
     font-size: 300%;
     line-height: 30px;
     padding: 10px 5px 0 5px;
     content: "";
 }
 div.entry-text > p > a::after {
     margin-top: 15px;
     content: "";
 }
 </style>
```

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you're looking for. Is this any help? http://jsfiddle.net/eatzvfks/

Comment: @garryp - Close, but I don't see the drop cap in the second paragraph on your fiddle. Are you seeing it? I want the drop-cap to work in both scenarios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `::first-letter` pseudo element is not working on **inline** elements. It only works if the parent is a block-level element. Since `p` is a block-level element it works just fine when there's only text.

If there's any other markup before the text such as `<a href>` or for example a `<div>`, `::first-letter` won't target the first letter, see an [example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gpbyzw) of what I am talking about.

***Suggestion 1:*** Wrap the text with a `span`, which is an inline element and set its `display` to `block`.

```css
div.entry-text > p > span::first-letter {
  color: red;
  font-size: 300%;
  line-height: 30px;
  padding: 0 0 0 0;
  content: "";
}
span {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="entry-text">
  <p>
    <span>This is some text</span>
  </p>
</div>

<div class="entry-text">
  <p>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="myimage.jpg" class="entry-image" />
    </a>
    <span>
        This is some text
    </span>
  </p>
</div>
```

---

***Suggestion 2:*** In the `.entry-text` with the `img`, use another `p` tag around the text.

```css
div.entry-text > p::first-letter {
  color: red;
  font-size: 300%;
  line-height: 30px;
  padding: 10px 5px 0 5px;
  content: "";
}
div.entry-text > p > a::after {
  margin-top: 15px;
  content: "";
}
div.entry-text > p > a > img {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="entry-text">
  <p>This is some text</p>
</div>

<div class="entry-text">
  <p>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="myimage.jpg" class="entry-image" />
    </a>

    <p>
      This is some text
    </p>
  </p>
</div>
```

---

***Suggestion 3*** (not the best one, but at least the `::first-letter` works): Put the `<img>` after the text and use `float:left;` to place it before text.

```css
div.entry-text > p::first-letter { 
     color: red;
     font-size: 300%;
     line-height: 30px;
     padding: 10px 5px 0 5px;
     content: "";
 }
 div.entry-text > p > a::after {
     margin-top: 15px;
     content: "";
 }

div.entry-text > p > a > img {
  float:left; 
}
```

```html
<div class="entry-text">
  <p>This is some text</p>
</div>

<div class="entry-text">
  <p>
    This is some text
    <a href="#">
      <img src="myimage.jpg" class="entry-image" />
    </a>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: That works, but I don't have the ability to insert a tag around the text. The user will be in control of everything inside the `<div class=entry-text>`. Any ideas?

Comment: I am not sure of what you are asking. Can you explain? By saying *"insert a tag around the text"* you mean anchor tag? Making it a link?

Comment: You're suggesting I add a `<span>` tag when you say "wrapping the text with a `span`". I'm saying I don't have the ability to do that. If possible, I need to write the css to do this without additional html tags.